# Mouse events are not routed to the NSButtons in Cocoa application

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

I have a couple of UI elements inside of 3 NSStackviews.
First NSStackView is a vertically oriented stackView and acts like a container for 2 child stackViews.
First child stackView has 3 NSButtons and second child stackView has 2 NSTextFields acting like a label and 1 NSSlider.
Up until today it worked as expected.
The issue is that all of my buttons and sliders stopped reacting on mouse events without any obvious reason.

What I tried:

- Rolled back a few commits to see if I messed up something and I found out that I did not. It does not receive mouse events on older commits as 
  well.
- I tried moving out UI elements from the NSStackView to see if I am overlapping something, but it did not work again.
- Since I added accessibility labels to the NSButtons, I removed them too, but it changed nothing.
- Tried building the project on another mac and got the same issue.
- Added override for keyDown event to see if that window is becoming first responder. Yes, it gets the mouse events perfectly, but my buttons still do not trigger their actions when clicked.

The strange thing is that buttons work using the voiceover and keyboard.

Additional info:

macOS: 10.14.2

Xcode: 10.1

Deployment target: 10.14

Edit: After doing basically nothing, it started responding to mouse events just as expected. This makes me worried because the app needs to be shipped next week, and stopping receiving mouse events without any reason would not be ideal.

Comment: By mouse events you mean mouseEntered/mouseExited/mouseUp/mouseDown/etc. or simply just @IBActions of your buttons?

Comment: I am referring to @IBActions / target actions. I also found out that sometimes if I resize the NSWindow, it starts working.

Comment: Do you override mouseDown/mouseUp in some other element? Once I had the very same issue and the problem was that other elements overrided mouseDown where I did not call super.mouseDown() so it stealed the event from other components.

Comment: No, I only override "keyDown" but it is not related to mouse. As I said in my first comment, the issue fixes itself after resizing a window couple of times. I am starting to assume that VLCKit VLCVideoView is doign something strange with the layout. Oh, I did not mention that these buttons are a subview of a VLCVideoView.